Output gets triggered on Startup - 555 timer Falling Edge Detection
The output of the circuit is supposed to go low for 100ms when the input goes low. But when I power it on, at that instant, the output goes low as well. The output is connected to another PMOS that will trigger a electromagnet.


Green is output. Blue is input.
Any help would be appreciated.

U2 has no connections to GND and Vss, and no input signal. What is that part supposed to do, and how do you think it will perform without those connections?

Try adding a delay to the Reset pin, a resistor to Vcc and a capacitor to ground. This will hold Reset low until the capacitor charges up through the resistor. Try maybe 10k resistor and 1 to 10 uF cap, play around with the values to get enough delay without having it take too long to start up.

This worked. Thanks!

Try connecting C3 to Vcc (plus supply) instead of ground.
Connect the (+) end of the capacitor to Vcc and the other end to the DIS-THRS node.  That way the node will be held high during the initial application of power, which should keep the 555 output low.
It will still operate normally after that since the capacitor doesn't care to which AC ground it is connected.
